# Using a custom keyboard to enter and manipulate data in EditText

Tags: android

I want the user to enter data in an `EditText` using a custom keypad. The custom keypad is integrated to the layout. It is not supposed to pop up when the EditText in question is in focus.

The problem I have is that I can't disable the soft keyboard without disabling the editing properties of the `EditText`: I want the user to be able to position the cursor for example.

I have tried using the `InputMethodManager`

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

but it doesn't work at least on some OS versions. The keyboard still pops up when I tap the EditText.

I have also tried setting the input mode:

```
edtView.setInputType(0)
```

but then I cannot position a cursor. I could [Selection.setSelection(Spannable txt, int index);](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Selection.html#setSelection%28android.text.Spannable,%20int%29) to position the cursor, but how to know the position the user has touched?

Comment: Why would you want to disable keyboard user is acquainted with?

Answer (score 0):

I never tried this myself, but the only thing that occurs to me is: have you tried adding an [OnEditorActionListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.OnEditorActionListener.html) to your EditText and calling `hideSoftInputFromWindow` every time you get an editor action?

Comment: Would't it be already to late? The keyboard would already be popped up before any action can be passed to the listener